# why the command in build step stopped with process exited with code 0, but still left some command didn't execute

Tags: teamcity

I have several command in build step of teamcity, however it will stop with process exited with code 0, and still left the command didn't execute, I can not figure out why?

Comment: We will have to see your build step and execution log.

Comment: maybe other steps has `Even if some of the previous steps failed` parameter